# Arguments of user-defined exception

Tags: python, oop, exception

I can't understand how the arguments of CustomException are initialized in the following case:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        print('init:', self.args)

ce = CustomException('error message')
print(ce.args)
```

The output is:

```
init: ('error message',)
('error message',)
```

It seems that during instantiation of CustomException the superclass constructor is called implicitly, but it should not.

Comment: FYI: your question was closed not because it is not goot (IMHO, it indeed deserves the upvotes) but because the answers are already provided in another question.